# Parameter-specific learning rate in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

How can I set a learning rate for each specific parameter (weights and biases) in a network?

On [PyTorch's docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/optim.html?highlight=optimizer) I found this:

```py
optim.SGD([{'params': model.base.parameters()}, 
           {'params': model.classifier.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}], 
           lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9)
```

where `model.classifier.parameters()`, which defines a group of parameters obtains a specific learning rate of 1e-3.

But how can I translate this into parameter level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set parameter-specific learning rate by using the parameter names to set the learning rates e.g.

For a given network taken from [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-set-different-learning-rate-for-weight-and-bias-in-one-layer/13450/6?u=kharshit):

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(1, 1)
        self.layer1.weight.data.fill_(1)
        self.layer1.bias.data.fill_(1)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(1, 1)
        self.layer2.weight.data.fill_(1)
        self.layer2.bias.data.fill_(1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        return self.layer2(x)

net = Net()
for name, param in net.named_parameters():
    print(name)
```

The parameters are:

```py
layer1.weight
layer1.bias
layer2.weight
layer2.bias
```

Then, you can use the parameter names to set their specific learning rates as follows:

```py
optimizer = optim.Adam([
            {'params': net.layer1.weight},
            {'params': net.layer1.bias, 'lr': 0.01},
            {'params': net.layer2.weight, 'lr': 0.001}
        ], lr=0.1, weight_decay=0.0001)

out = net(torch.Tensor([[1]]))
out.backward()
optimizer.step()
print("weight", net.layer1.weight.data.numpy(), "grad", net.layer1.weight.grad.data.numpy())
print("bias", net.layer1.bias.data.numpy(), "grad", net.layer1.bias.grad.data.numpy())
print("weight", net.layer2.weight.data.numpy(), "grad", net.layer2.weight.grad.data.numpy())
print("bias", net.layer2.bias.data.numpy(), "grad", net.layer2.bias.grad.data.numpy())
```

Output:

```py
weight [[0.9]] grad [[1.0001]]
bias [0.99] grad [1.0001]
weight [[0.999]] grad [[2.0001]]
bias [1.] grad [1.]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it even possible to access a conv filters weights specifically?

Comment: You can use `.weight` and `.bias` corresponding to every layer _(whose name you can get by looping over `.parameters()` as I did)_ for conv layer as well.

Comment: I meant accessing each parameter in a kernel like that: `{'params': model.conv.weight[0, 0, 0, 0], 'lr': 0.1}`. Unfortunately that gives me an error: `ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor`

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done this way in this case. I'll check if it's possible.

Comment: I may have found a way. It is necessary to create a new optimizer and change the last line in the `step` method of `torch.optim.Adam` to: `p.data.add_((-step_size * (exp_avg.type(torch.double) / denom.type(torch.double))).type(torch.float32))`